# google open automation framework - perl oaf - getpgrp() error

Tags: perl

I have problems with OAF, run_tests.pl returns an error

C:\Perl\oaf\bin>run_tests.pl
The getpgrp() function is unimplemented at C:/Perl/oaf/bin/../lib/Oaf/Config.pm line 345.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at C:/Perl/oaf/bin/../lib/Oaf/Config.pm line 390.
Use of uninitialized value $config in concatenation (.) or string at C:/Perl/oaf/bin/../lib/Oaf/Con
ig.pm line 394.

can you help me ?

http://code.google.com/p/google-oaf/

Comment: Your question isn't properly formatted, and it's unclear. What did you do? Did you create a test suite? Show us the test suite code, else it's meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

getpgrp() is not implemented for Windows so that probably means OAF won't run on a Windows platform.